# jQuery not listening for clicks on dynamically generated elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

So in my few-months-long quest to learn JavaScript, I finally sat down and built Minesweeper.  As a bonus, it actually works! (er, well.. the first time).

The problem is that if I clear my board and then again dynamically generate the new game board, none of my jQuery click listeners work any longer.  The game works on the first document load, but clicks don't register after.

**Full jfiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/3w5zm64y/

**The part relevant to this question:**

**index.html**

```
<table class="gameBoard"></table> //the game board is dynamically generated inside of this table
```

**JS code**

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
    ....
    //right click check
        $(".left").find('td').on('mousedown',function(e){
          if( e.button == 2 ) {
             alert('this works only on the first page load');
          } 
        }

    $('.gameBoard').text(''); //this is where I clear out everything within the gameBoard table
    draw_board(numRows,numCols);  //this method puts everything back into the gameBoard table
```

**problem:**

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
    ....
    //right click check
        $(".left").find('td').on('mousedown',function(e){
          if( e.button == 2 ) {
             alert('**now this doesn't work!**');
          } 
        }
```

I've looked through all related questions that I could find here on SO and elsewhere.  Per that advice, I've tested the below code but that also doesn't work after re-generating my table

```
$(document).ready(function(){
....
//right click check
    $(".left").on('mousedown','td',function(e){
```

Comment: `location.reload()` is not an option, I guess? :-)

Comment: May be while clearing the board, are you removing the '.left' container too? In that case you have to bind on('mousedown') event again on the '.left' container.

Comment: If you are removing the `.left` nodes, you are losing the bindings. Bind to something which is always present.

Comment: Whoever downvoted tomtom - why? He asked a valid question, formatted it well, put in examples and even a jsfiddle. What more could he do other than not asking the question and suffering in silence??

Comment: Thanks @Mathletics, that was the solution Yaje pointed out.  I didn't even think that I wasn't binding it to one of the things that was being destroyed/recreated

Comment: @CaspNZ that was my bad; I should have found one of the 2000 dupes of this question and voted to close rather than downvoting. The question itself is great, it's just a very common question.

Comment: @Mathletics - my bad for not realising it's such a common question. Turns out there is a whole slew of "should we enforce reasons for downvotes" questions on meta - and actually, it seems the consensus is that reasons should not be required - that's the beauty of democracy.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you have to use `document` as your selector

like this :

```
$(document).on('mousedown','.left td',function(e){
  if( e.button == 2 ) {
      if($(this).hasClass('blank')){
          $(this).removeClass('blank');
          $(this).addClass('flag');
          $(this).text('');
          $(this).append('<img src="http://www.chezpoor.com/minesweeper/images/bombflagged.gif">'); //add flag if it's blank
      } else if($(this).hasClass('flag')) {
          $(this).removeClass('flag');
          $(this).addClass('blank');
          $(this).text('');
          $(this).append('<img src="http://www.chezpoor.com/minesweeper/images/blank.gif">'); //back to blank
      }
  }
});

//left click check
 $(document).on('mousedown','.left td',function(e){
      if( e.button === 0 ) {
          checkCell($(this).attr('id'));
      }
```

this way it will work also with generated elements

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/3w5zm64y/2/)

**Note** :

> as for code and performance optimization refer to @cyk's comment below
>   regarding the event performance

Comment: yes, yes, yes, 1,000,000 times yes. Thank you, this is it. In 3 minutes you fixed what I'd been staring at for over an hour. Thank you! Will accept in 5 minutes when it allows me

Comment: anytime mate. no problem

Comment: Just to clarify, your events need to be attached to a common parent element that will not be removed. For example, "document" as Yaje helpfully suggested or you could even attach the events to ".gameBoard".

Comment: I recently learned to be careful not to abuse attaching to document, as performance will degrade when you have many. It's better to attach to an element closer to the one you want to bind--the only requirement is that you need to attach to one that's already in the DOM and will not be removed. In this case `$('.gameboard').on(...)` will work. http://api.jquery.com/on/#event-performance.

Comment: Ah that makes a lot of sense. I'm destroying .left, so of course the listener goes away.  I could have used .gameBoard instead of document as @cyk suggested.  Thanks all, this was great to learn

Comment: Yes. @cyk Thank you for that wonderful information. can i use your suggestion and edit the answer for sake of other future SO users?

Answer (score 2):

When you recreate the board, you destroy all listeners.

Put the listeners at the end of draw board and it works fine.

http://jsfiddle.net/3w5zm64y/4/

```
function draw_board(x,y){
    ...
    createListeners();
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    ..
    // init functions
    draw_board(numRows,numCols); 
});

function createListeners() {
   // add listeners here
}
```